# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: XXX cannot be cast to spark.servlet.SparkApplication

Tags: java, maven, spark-java

I am new to java. I am working on a web service on tomcat. When I deploy the WAR file in webapps folder,

SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [SparkFilter]
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: HelloWorld cannot be cast to spark.servlet.SparkApplication

This error could be seen in the log of tomcat. I am using sparkjava to create the service.

Here is my code

```
import spark.servlet.SparkApplication;

//import static spark.Spark.get;

import static spark.Spark.*;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        get("/clipboard/:text", (req, res) -> {
            StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(req.params(":text"));
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
            return req.params(":text");
        });


    }
}
```

And my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sparkjava-hello-world</groupId>
    <artifactId>sparkjava-hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[1.8,)</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Is there any problem of my code or which dependencies or plugin or procedure when exporting as WAR file is missing in my project file?

Thank you for any advice.

**Update** I have figured it out i have to call the function in @Override
    public void init(){}, but when i deploy on server, i cannot copy things to clipboard through server. Is that related to the server? Only OpenJDK is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude Jetty in the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```